# delete words after a certain character repetition?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have strings like:

```
'John Lasseter , Pete Docter , Andrew Stanton , Joe Ranft , Joss Whedon , Andrew Stanton , Joel Cohen , Alec Sokolow '
```

or:

```
'Jonathan Hensleigh , Greg Taylor , Jim Strain , Greg Taylor , Jim Strain , Chris Van Allsburg , Chris Van Allsburg'
```

I want to delete everything after the third name. For example in the first string , I want to have :

```
John Lasseter , Pete Docter , Andrew Stanton
```

how can I do that in python?

Comment: `",".join(s.split(",")[:3])`

Answer (score 5):

No real need to use `re` for this; just use the **[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)** method on strings and index the list that is returned:

```
s = 'John Lasseter , Pete Docter , Andrew Stanton , Joe Ranft , Joss Whedon , Andrew Stanton , Joel Cohen , Alec Sokolow ' 
s.split(',')[:3]
# returns: ['John Lasseter ', ' Pete Docter ', ' Andrew Stanton ']
```

Will give you the first three names in the list, as a list.

Using [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with `",".join(s.split(',')[:3])` will additionally join them together in new string containing the comma-seperated names:

```
>>> ",".join(s.split(',')[:3])
# returns: 'John Lasseter , Pete Docter , Andrew Stanton '
```

Comment: Your welcome, if a particular answer is helpful in solving your problem, mark it as "accepted" by clicking the little checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking you would probably be better suited by a function

```
def trim_after_repeat(source, delimiter, count = 3):
    # This breaks the string into a list of strings based on your delimiter 
    pieces = source.split(delimiter)
    # This sets items_wanted to match the count you want
    items_wanted = pieces[0:count]
    # This puts the items_wanted back together
    return delimiter.join(items_wanted)

string_to_trim = 'John Lasseter , Pete Docter , Andrew Stanton , Joe Ranft ,'
print(trim_after_repeat(string_to_trim), ' , ')

# 'John Lasseter ,  Pete Docter ,  Andrew Stanton'
```